# Pokemon Go, all progress lost?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I have been using the app for 3 days now. I just opened it up again, and it asked me to sign "up" again with either Google or the Trainer server.

So I signed up with the same Google account as when I first started with and the game started again.

Is there Any way I can get my progress back?

Answer (score 3):

Pokemon Go FAQs has mentioned this, where if you log into the wrong account by accident, possibly by clicking "Pokemon trainer club" when you meant to click Google, you wil end up in a second account. Try logging out and logging back in again, making sure you go into the Google account.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, try logging out and back in, ensuring you are using the correct account login.

Also, it was reported on a post I read (can't find the link) that a few other people had this issue. They completely shut down the app and then relogged, and it fixed their problem. I suggest that course of action. If it doesn't work, I would try again a little later with the same method. If it fails the second time, then either contact niantic or just restart